# My first "if" statement says that it is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

My first `if` statement says that it is not working.

```
import random
RandomNum = random.randint(1, 10) 
Hall = {
 if(RandomNum <= 8)
    1 : {
           "item" : "sword"
            }
  elif(RandomNum == "5")
    2 : {
           "mob" : "skeleton"
          }
}
```

Comment: based on the code you've submitted, it's not clear what you're trying to do here. Please add more information about the expected outcome from the statement you've added

Comment: Problems: First you compare RandomNum to a number and then to a string ("5"). Also: What should the 1: and the 2: be?

Comment: The 1: and 2: are the dictionary definitions but I dont know what to do... It says the f in if is invalid syntax...

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but you cannot use `if/elif` statements inside an expression like you're doing here. There's also some issues with typing (`RandomNum` can never be `"5"`, since the latter is a string and the former will always be an int)

Maybe you're trying to do:

```
Hall = {}

# note that I reversed the order here, since
# your first `if` encapsulated the predicate of the elif
if RandomNum == 5:
    Hall[2] = {"mob": "skeleton"}
elif RandomNum <= 8:
    Hall[1] = {"item": "sword"}
```

Comment: @TheBannanaJoe N.B that you *can* use `if/else` statements in expressions. `a if predicate else b` is the ternary operator in Python. If `predicate` evaluates to `True`, this expression evaluates to `a`. If `predicate` is `False`, the whole thing is `b`.